# Placing black and white balls in a row, s.t. no pair of black balls is lying side by side

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

> In how many ways can we dispose $m$ white and $n$ black balls such that there is no pair of black balls lying side by side ?

If $n>m+1$ it is not possible, if not;

I place the black balls, such that there is always a slot between them

$\underbrace{\_b\_b\_b\_b\_b\_b\_b\_b\_...}_{\text{n black balls, n+1 slots}}$

Then i have to put at least $n-1$ between the blacks, (I think the balls are indistinguishable, it doesn't matter which white balls i place, i don't need the factor $\binom{m}{n-1}$)

Then i repeat the method with the slots again

$\_bw\_bw\_bw\_bw\_bw\_bw\_bw\_bw\_...$

I have $m-(n-1)=m-n+1$ white balls and $n+1$ slots left. The answer is $(m-n+1)^{n+1}$, Is that correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track but not quite there.  Here is one way to solve the problem.

We have to use $n-1$ white balls to separate the black balls.  So put these balls to one side.  We now have $n$ black balls and $m-(n-1)$ white balls, which is $m+1$ balls altogether.  The number of possible patterns of white and black (and for now, black balls side by side *are* allowed) is found by simply choosing $n$ places out of $m+1$ for the black balls.  The number of ways is $C(m+1,n)$.  Now restore the reserved white balls, one between each pair of black balls and regardless of whether there is already a white ball there.

So $C(m+1,n)$ is the final answer.

An example to assist in understanding this: say we have $10$ white balls and $4$ black.  Set aside $3$ white balls and arrange the remaining balls.  For example we could get
$$WWBWWWBBWBW\ .$$
Now restore the $3$ white balls to get
$$WWBWWWWBWBWWBW\ .$$
This will probably take a bit of thought, it is one of the harder among "elementary" counting problems.

Comment: Hi @Stefanos, if $m=n$ you could also place them BWWBWBWBWBW...B and various other ways.  You could start with BWBW...BWB and then you have to place the remaining W.  It could go in one of the $n-1$ gaps between Bs or in either of the two spots at the ends.  So there's your $n+1$.

Comment: Ok, true, thanks! +10 also from me then!

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $m=n+k$ for some $k\ge -1$ otherwise as you said it is not possible. Now, make $n$ pairs of black and white balls of the form $bw$. So the new problem is to count all the ways you can place the $n$ new balls (of the form $bw$) and the remaining $k=m-n$ white balls in a row, with no restrictions. This is equal to $$\dbinom{n+k}{n}$$ Note however that this number gives only solutions that end with a white ball (due to the choice $bw$), so we have to count additionally those that end with a black ball which can be found if we fix a black ball in the last slot and then repeat the process with $n-1$ pairs of the form $bw$ and $k+1$ white balls. Then there are similarly $$\dbinom{n-1+k+1}{n-1}=\dbinom{n+k}{n-1}$$ ways to do it. In sum, there are $$\dbinom{n+k}{n}+\dbinom{n+k}{n-1}$$ ways to place the balls in the required manner. By Pascal's rule the above expression can be reduced to $$\dbinom{n+k+1}{n}=\dbinom{n+m-n+1}{n}=\dbinom{m+1}{n}$$

Comment: @O.B.D.A. The other answer covers you completely. I just posted it because - after David explained the m=n case - I understood that this way also works (because until then I thought that m=n should yield 2 ways).

Comment: interesting approach. I know pascal's recursion, but what do you do in the last line ?

Comment: @O.B.D.A. In the last line I replace $k$ with $m-n$ because in the beginning I defined $k$ in the equation $m=n+k$. The pascal's  recursion is this one from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule)