# Is this solution correct? 4

Tags: combinatorics

There are $3$ black balls and $18$ white balls. In how many ways the balls can be arranged such that no two black balls are together?

Solution:

The number of ways of arranging all the balls is:$\large \frac{21!}{3!}$ and the number of ways of arranging the balls such that two black balls are together, is:$\large \frac{20!}{2!}$,(Put two black ones together, now we have $20$ balls out of which $2$ are of the same kind) so $\large \frac{21!}{3!}-\large \frac{20!}{2!}$ should be the answer, is it correct?

Comment: I don't think you have counted the cases where at least two black balls are together correctly.  You would need to consider the case where you have 2 black balls together but not the third, and then the case where all 3 blacks are together.

Comment: if the balls are not distinguishable, $\frac{21!}{3!}$ is a huge number isn't it ?

Comment: @user84413 Put two black balls together ,now we have $20$ balls, out of which two are of the same kind.

Comment: see also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/707938/129458

Comment: @HashimKhan I have added a solution using the subtraction method below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$  First arrange the white balls in a row, and then count how many ways you can insert the black balls in the resulting gaps.

(This is assuming balls of the same color are identical.)

---

If we want to work this by subtraction instead, we can start with the total number of arrangements of the balls, which is $\binom{21}{3}=\frac{21!}{18!3!}$,
and then subtract the number of arrangements with two black balls together.

There are $\binom{19}{1}=19$ arrangements with all 3 black balls together, and there are $19\cdot18$ arrangements with only two of the black balls together (since we can first remove one of the white balls, arrange the remaining 17 whites and the single black and the double black in $\frac{19!}{17!}=19\cdot18$ ways, and then insert the other white ball between the single black and double black).

Therefore there are $\displaystyle\frac{21!}{18!3!}-19-19\cdot18=969$ possibilities.